# Парсинг json файла

Tags: python, json, парсер

При парсинге json фалов мне надо взять одну информацию из всех файлов, но получаю ошибку.
Вот код:

```
import json
adress=[]
for d in range(1,485,1):
    with open(f"data/{d}.json","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
        r=json.load(file)
        for i in r['result']['items']:
            adress.append((i['full_name']))
print(adress)
```

Ошибка такая:

```
for i in r['result']['items']:
KeyError: 'result'
```

Хотя при написании одного json файла ошибки нет. Мне кажется ошибка из- за первого цикла. Можете подсказать как избавиться от нее.

Comment: Значит нет в каком то файле этого `result`. Сделайте банальный `print(f"data/{d}.json")` и узнаете на каком файле он упал. Ну и смотрите что там.

Answer (score 0):

Нет `result` в файле. Выведите `d` и вручную просмотрите файл! Возможно был сбой записи в файл.